# Typo3: Extbase extension: How can view be reloaded every 20 seconds?

Tags: typo3, reload, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have an Extbase extension starting some background activities. To monitor the overall progress, there is a view displaying current state. How can this view be reloaded, say every 10-15 seconds? The best thing was to reload only this part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX. To get the result of a specific action instead of the whole page, you can use the extension [typoscript_rendering](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typoscript_rendering) - it's made for this exact purpose.

To use it, you need to do something along these lines:

1. Create a controller action that renders the output you want to use for reloading.
2. In the fluid template where you want to reload the output, render the URL to use for rendering that output using the ViewHelper `helhum:uri.ajaxAction` from the above-mentioned extension. Put it into some data-attribute or something.
3. Fetch the content at that URL using AJAX - if you need adapt parameters for each call, it's probably best to do POST requests. You need to implement this manually - TYPO3 does not come with prebuilt JS for this.

Comment: Yes AJAX was the first thing I thought of. For a few years I had to deal with Ruby on Rails and such thing were really easy there.  
I have a simple TYPOScript template. The whole logic is in Fluid. Is there any simple way in AJAX to reload Fluid output by calling an action?

Comment: You should probably have extbase controllers and actions... Usually, you don't have all you logic in the templates, but put it into controllers, services and domain models, and use fluid only for display.

Comment: Yes, it that way with controllers, models and views.  
With *logic* I meant *template logic*. I didn't change *TYPOScript template* generated by *Extension Builder*.

Comment: I've updated the answer - you don't need to change your TypoScript template, only your fluid templates, the JS, and maybe the controller.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I'll mark the question as answered, but I doubt I can implement things I need this way. It sounds really complex.

Comment: It's not that complex - just have a controller action rendering what you need, put the URL to it somewhere, and do HTTP requests to it...